# Using __new__ on classes derived from Django's models does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is something which is puzzling me, but I cannot get a definitive answer. Using the `__new__` method (or more accurately, static method) within classes derived from DJango model.

This is how `__new__` should be ideally used (since we are using Django, we can assume that version 2.x of python is being used):

```
class A(object):
  def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print ("This is A's new function")
    return super(A, self).__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  def __init__(self):
    print ("This is A's init function")
```

Instantiating an object from the above class works as expected. Now, when one tries something like this on classes derived from Django models, something unexpected happens:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Test, self).__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Instantiating an object from the above class results in this error: 
`TypeError: unbound method __new__() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)`.

I can't understand why this is happening (although I know some class magic is happening behind the scenes due to the Django framework).

Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you need to clean up your code. In that last snippet, should it be `test` or `Test`? Also, your indentation is off.

Comment: Yes, the `return super(test, self)...` should be `return super(Test, sefl)...`.

Comment: Hi guys - sorry, I typed the example really quickly in the editor (I did not copy and paste code there) - so apologies for the incorrectness. It still does not work, even if your above two comments are taken into account. BTW: I have fixed the code snippets above.

Comment: Does `models.Model.__new__(Test, *args, **kwargs)` work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__new__` doesn't receive an instance as its first parameter. How could it when (a) it's a static method, as you note, and (b) its job is to create an instance and return it! The first parameter of `__new__` is conventionally called `cls`, as it is the class.

Which makes the error message you quote very weird; it is normally the error message you'd get when you called an **unbound method** (i.e. what you get by accessing `ClassName.methodName`) with something other than an instance of that class as the `self` parameter. However, staticmethods (including `__new__`) don't become unbound methods, they're just simple functions that happen to be attributes of a class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls)
    def method(self):
        pass

>>> class Bar(object):
    pass

>>> Foo.method
<unbound method Foo.method>

>>> Foo.__new__
<function __new__ at 0x0000000002DB1C88>

>>> Foo.method(Bar())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo.method(Bar())
TypeError: unbound method method() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got Bar instance instead)

>>> Foo.__new__(Bar)
<__main__.Bar object at 0x0000000002DB4F28>
```

You can see from this that `__new__` should never be an unbound method. Furthermore (unlike a normal method) it doesn't care that you're consistent in what you pass it; I have actually managed to construct an instance of `Bar` by calling `Foo.__new__` because both it and `Bar.__new__` are ultimately implemented the same way (deferring all actual work to `object.__new__`).

However, this led me to look at the source code of Django itself, briefly. Django's `Model` class has a metaclass, `ModelBase`. Which is quite complex, and I didn't figure out what it's doing entirely, but I did notice something very interesting.

`ModelBase.__new__` (the *metaclass* `__new__`, which is the function that creates the *class* at the end of your class block) invokes its super `__new__` **without passing it your class dictionary**. It instead passes a dictionary with only the `__module__` attribute set. Then, after doing a whole bunch of processing, it does the following:

```
    # Add all attributes to the class.
    for obj_name, obj in attrs.items():
        new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
```

(`attrs` is the dictionary containing all your definitions in your class block, including your `__new__` function; `add_to_class` is a metaclass method that is mostly just `setattr`).

I'm now 99% certain that the problem is here, because `__new__` is a weird *implicitly* static method. So unlike every other static method, you haven't applied the `staticmethod` decorator to it. Python (at some level) just recognises the `__new__` method and processes it as a static method rather than a normal method[1]. But I'll bet this only happens when you define `__new__` in a class block, not when you set it using `setattr`.

So your `__new__`, which should be a static method but hasn't been processed by the `staticmethod` decorator, is being converted into a normal instance method. Then when Python calls it passing the **class** `Test`, as per the normal instance creation protocol, it complains that it's not getting an instance of `Test`.

If that's all correct, then:

1. This fails because Django is a bit broken, but only in that it fails to take Python's inconsistency about `__new__` being static into account.
2. You could probably make this work by applying `@staticmethod` to your `__new__` method, even though you shouldn't have to.

---

[1] I believe this is a historical quirk of Python, since `__new__` was introduced before the `staticmethod` decorator, but `__new__` **can't** take an instance, since there's no instance to call it on.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Ben. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. It works perfectly now when I use the static decorator.

Comment: `__new__` could also be `classmethod`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It could, in the sense that it obviously *should* be a classmethod, looking at it logically. However normal `__new__` methods most definitely are *not* classmethods, they are staticmethods. Again this is a historical quirk, as `__new__` predates the `classmethod` decorator. Given that `__new__` is already 'special', and relied on by the core of Python's OO model, I would not try using a classmethod `__new__` in production code, although it may well work.

Comment: @Ben: it is a comment on "has to be static" i.e., `__new__` *is* a `staticmethod` but it *could* be `classmethod`. BDFL says `__new__` is the reason `classmethod` appeared.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ah! I was using "static" to mean only "doesn't act on an instance" in that sentence, but you're quite right, it's confusing. I've reworded it.