# Is it safe to set __new__ on Django model classes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaprogramming, django-orm

This question is different from: [Using __new__ on classes derived from Django's models does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100409/using-new-on-classes-derived-from-djangos-models-does-not-work)

*That* question asks how one can make `__new__` work.

**This question asks**: What are the pitfalls of using `__new__` with Django models?

In particular, I have the following code, which exists to install a classmethod on the class, which needs to know which class it originates in (i.e. it needs to tell whether it is being called on a subclass or not). **Will this blow up in unexpected ways?**

```
class Director(models.Model, Specializable, DateFormatter, AdminURL, Supercedable): # my own mixin classes
    # all other properties etc snipped

    @staticmethod # necessary with django models
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        Specializable.create_subclass_translator(cls, install = 'create_from_officer')
        return models.Model.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

For completeness, `create_subclass_translator` does something like this:

```
@classmethod
def create_subclass_translator(clazz, Baseclass, install=None):       
    def create_from_other_instance(selfclass, old_instance, properties):
        if selfclass is Baseclass: raise TypeError("This method cannot be used on the base class")
        # snipped for concision
        return selfclass(**properties)

    new_method = classmethod(create_from_other_instance)

    if install and not hasattr(Baseclass, install):
        setattr(Baseclass, install, new_method)

    return new_method
```

For those who wonder what this is accomplishing, the classmethod `create_from_other_instance` is a factory which simulates a model subclass instance changing from one subclass to another, by copying over the baseclass properties, and setting the `ancestor_link` property correctly.

Comment: Any good reasons for such complexity?

Comment: @Secator: Firstly, I don't see this as especially complex. In any case, the reason for this is that I need to have the same functionality in several class hierarchies, and as noted, these methods need to know about their own class. To accomplish that in another way would require either copy-and-paste; or a magic auxiliary method per baseclass that returns that class itself; or to perform the installation outside of the definition of the class. All of those invite their own subtle bugs.

Comment: Have you looked at the BaseModel class? I'm fairly certain it defines a __new__ method as well. You would need to call super, I think, once you do what you need to do in your own method, otherwise the class will not instantiate the way Django expects it to. Notably, you won't have a Meta class or a Media class (where appropriate). These are just some thoughts off the top of my head.

Comment: @JamesR: I will take a look at BaseModel. Note that django.models.Model inherits from BaseModel, and I am calling the __new__ on that. Or is there a reason to user `super` rather than using the name of the base class?

Comment: no - you can call the base class by the name if it is not changing along the project lifetime. "super" can be rather unintuitive sometimes.

Comment: Do you know that you're creating new classmethods each time a new instance of a class is created?

Comment: @Secator: Yes. Apart from the instantiation overhead, this is harmless, as all but the first instance is thrown away. I could, of course have `__new__` replace itself, but that would seem needlessly complex.

Comment: In Python 3.3+ you may run into `TypeError`s when calling `__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34777773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are properly calling the base class `__new__`, I would not expect surprises there - it should just work - and if done wrong, fail at once at instantiation.

You should not have any subtle errors there - just write some unit tests that instantiate this class. If it ever become "wrong" the tests will fail.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, if I knew about possible failure modes I would test for those specifically ;)