# TypeError: object() takes no parameters after defining __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really don't get where the error is in this little piece of code:

```
class Personne:
    def __init__(self, nom, prenom):
        print("Appel de la méthode __init__")
        self.nom = nom
        self.prenom = prenom

    def __new__(cls, nom, prenom):
        print("Appel de la méthode __new__ de la classe {}".format(cls))
        return object.__new__(cls, nom, prenom)

personne = Personne("Doe", "John")
```

It is giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilal/Lien vers python/21_meta_classes/1_instanciation.py", line 21, in <module>
    personne = Personne("Doe", "John")
  File "/home/bilal/Lien vers python/21_meta_classes/1_instanciation.py", line 14, in __new__
    return object.__new__(cls, nom, prenom)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Python 3.3 and later, if you're overriding both `__new__` and `__init__`, you need to avoid passing any extra arguments to the `object` methods you're overriding. If you only override one of those methods, it's allowed to pass extra arguments to the other one (since that usually happens without your help).

So, to fix your class, change the `__new__` method like so:

```
def __new__(cls, nom, prenom):
    print("Appel de la méthode __new__ de la classe {}".format(cls))
    return object.__new__(cls) # don't pass extra arguments here!
```

Comment: FWIW, the OP's code actually works in Python3.2, though the error indeed occurs in Python3.3+

Comment: Thanks bro, it seems that it is working. please, tell me, how does python pass the rest of the arguments to __init__ , can you explain the process to me (if you have time of course) ??!!

Comment: The call to `__init__` isn't made by `object.__new__`, but rather by `type.__call__` (bound to the class object). So `object.__new__` doesn't need to see the same arguments that your `__init__` function expects.

Comment: @Blckknght do you know why it works that way in Python3.3+? Is it described somewhere? I could not find description of this behavior in the doc?

Comment: I think I've an answer now. It's hidden in comment in typeobject.c: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a4bbcd479ce86f68bbe12bc8c16e3447f32e13a/Objects/typeobject.c#L3538