# Inconsistency when overriding object.__new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, object, constructor

In both Python 2 and 3, the following code

```
class A(object):
    pass

A(1)
```

expectedly raises the following exception

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

However, the following code

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

A(1)
```

Does not raise anything. How come?

Comment: Good question. It *looks* like `type.__call__` (which is what actually calls `A.__new__` when you run `A(1)`) simply does not call `A.__init__` if `A.__new__` is defined but `A.__init__` is not.

Comment: However, `object.__init__` appears to ignore any additional arguments that it receives if you call it directly, while it (or something) raises an error if `super().__init__` tries to call it with additional arguments: which is to say, it's hard to tell if `object.__init_` isn't being called, or if it is and it just silently ignores the extra argument. Figuring out what exactly happens require digging into source code for the Python implementation.

Comment: Here is the source code for `type.__call__` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L974-L1040

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: object() takes no parameters after defining \_\_new\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777773/typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters-after-defining-new)  (The answer matches better than the question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in how `object.__new__` [1] and `object.__init__` [2] handle extra arguments.

Let's walk through a couple examples:

```
class A(object):
    pass

>>> A(1)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

- First, `object.__new__` is called. It gets the `1` argument. We didn't override `__new__` so this is false [1] and it doesn't throw an error. We didn't override `__init__` so this is true [2] and throws an error.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A.__init__({0}, {1}, {2})".format(self, args, kwargs))

>>> A(1)
A.__init__(<__main__.A object at 0xdeadbeef>, (1, ), {})
<__main__.A at 0xdeadbeef>
```

- First, `object.__new__` is called. It gets the `1` argument. We didn't override `__new__` so this is false [3] and it doesn't throw an error. We did override `__init__` so this is false [4] and doesn't throw an error.
- Second, `A.__init__` is called. Because it doesn't call `super`, `object.__init__` is never called.

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A.__new__({0}, {1}, {2})".format(cls, args, kwargs))
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

>>> A(1)
A.__new__(<class '__main__.A'>, (1,), {})
<__main__.A at 0xdeadbeef>
```

- First, `A.__new__` is called. It gets the `1` argument. We call `object.__new__` with no arguments.
- Second, `object.__init__` is called. It gets the `1` argument. We didn't override `__init__` so this is false [5] and it doesn't throw an error. We did override `__new__` so this is false [6] and it doesn't throw an error.

[1] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3866

[2] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3847

[3] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3867

[4] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3872

[5] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3848

[6] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04fc4f2a46b2fd083639deb872c3a3037fdb47d6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3853

Comment: What interpreter is this? Your last class definition doesn't call `__init__` at all, because `__new__` returns `None`