# Django model class __new__, what are the correct parameters to pass to super().__new__?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

What are the correct parameters to pass to `super().__new__` when I implement `__new__` in a Django `Model` class?

Most Django model classes do not need a custom `__new__` constructor, but I'm implementing one (for purposes that I think are not relevant to this question).

(Yes, I know that the `__init__` initialiser method is correct for customising an instance *after* creation. My intention is to customise the instance *before* the `__init__` method is called; this is what `__new__` is for.)

The Python documentation for [the constructor method, `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is unclear about exactly what parameters *must* be passed. It says that the method:

> […] takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument. The remaining arguments are those passed to the object constructor expression (the call to the class). The return value of **new**() should be the new object instance (usually an instance of cls).
>
> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking the superclass’s **new**() method using super().**new**(cls[, ...]) with appropriate arguments and then modifying the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it.

### Failure: Pass-through of `*args, **kwargs`

The above documentation implies that a “typical” `__new__` implementation should:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    do_some_customisation_of(instance)
    return instance
```

When I try to do this on a Django model class:

```python
class LoremIpsum(django.db.models.Model):
    id = django.db.models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, …)
    dolor = django.db.models.FileField(…)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        do_some_customisation_of(instance.dolor)
        return instance
```

Python raises a `TypeError` complaining I have passed too many parameters:

```
  File "…/models.py", line 83, in __new__
    instance = super().__new__(cls, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Strange; surely it is the implementation of `django.db.models.Model.__new__` that is responsible for calling `object.__new__` with the correct parameters?

### Failure: Pass-through no arguments

But okay, I'll try removing all the parameters in my `__new__` implementation:

```python
class LoremIpsum(django.db.models.Model):
    id = django.db.models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, …)
    dolor = django.db.models.FileField(…)

    def __new__(cls):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        do_some_customisation_of(instance.dolor)
        return instance
```

Python again raises a `TypeError`, this time complaining my `__new__` method has too *few* arguments:

```
  File "…/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 270, in build_instance
    return Model(**data)
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

That's expected; the `Model` class is of course attempting to define model fields on the new instance, so they should be passed along the chain of constructors.

### What other alternative?

These seem incompatible. If the pass-through cannot be nothing, and cannot be the arguments received, then some other way must be correct. But what?

What is the **correct method signature and parameters to pass for a `__new__` method on a Django model**?

Comment: Don't override `__new__` override `__init__` instead. From the docs: `__new__() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation`

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for responding. You're correct that the initialiser (`__init__`) is appropriate in more cases. But it's also quite normal to override the constructor (`__new__`) when needed; I have updated the question.

Comment: @bignose 2 years later, have you found an explanation / a solution? Your issue seems to be still relevant in 2022 and your question was very clear, but no answer here... Maybe this is related to this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100409/using-new-on-classes-derived-from-djangos-models-does-not-work